# Is it possible to use kotlinx json to format the toString method of a generic class?

Tags: json, kotlinx.serialization

I have a complicated data class with a generic parameter and I would like the `toString` method to display the whole class in a clean way. Instead of writing my own complex toString logic, I figured I would just use the pretty printed json version.

Here is what I would like to happen:

```
private val json = Json {
    prettyPrint = true
}

data class ComplicatedClass<E>(
    val oneOfManyNestedValues: Int
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return json.encodeToString(this)
    }
}
```

This does not work, because encodeToString really needs the type parameter to be reified. I cannot do this for the parameter `T` because it's a class type variable, not for a function.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this? Or do I need to give up on making my `toString` function the way I want?